# Download Pdf with php, Not working in explorer and safari

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, header

I've got a script to download pdf after submitting a form to db works fine on chrome and firefox but when i download my pdf on safari or explorer my pdf is empty and cannot be opened, i have tried many things, right now im using javascript whit window.location and it works on safari and explorer but i would really like my php script to work on all browsers

```
<?php
ob_start();


if ($_REQUEST["action"] == "download") {
    $file = base64_decode($_REQUEST["download"]);

//Insert to download table....

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }
    if (strlen(strstr($agent, 'Firefox')) > 0) {
        $browser = 'firefox';
    } else if (strlen(strstr($agent, 'Chrome')) > 0) {
        $browser = 'chrome';
    } else  {
        $browser = 'safari';
    }

    if ($browser == 'safari'){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = '<?php echo $file;?>';
    </script>
<?php 
    } else { ?>
<?php
        if ($file) { 

            header('Pragma: public');  // required
            header('Expires: 0');  // no cache
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

            header('Cache-Control: private', false);
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($file)) . ' GMT');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); // provide file size
            header('Connection: close');
            readfile($file);

            exit(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, could you add a *var_dump($file)* in your script and post the output of this var_dump here?
 I think it's just a problem with the file's name...

Comment: string(97) "mysite/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/12/diplom.pdf"

Comment: Are you sure this file exists? Remember that when you use a relative path, apache you use the same directory of the script being executed as root directory...

Comment: yes the file exist i can dowload it on booth chrome and firefox whit this script, and with javascript on explorer and safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing some of the headers, now im only using this

```
<?php
ob_start();


if ($_REQUEST["action"] == "download") {
$file = base64_decode($_REQUEST["download"]);


if ($file) { 
header('Pragma: public');  // required
header('Expires: 0');  // no cache
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile($file);
exit();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the function `ob_flush();` if you want to publish this kind of document in explorer

Comment: sjmg ive tried with both ob_flush() and ob_clean(), the result is my browser opens php file like

    %PDF-1.7 %âãÏÓ 67 0 obj <> endobj xref 67 32 0000000016 00000 n 000..

Comment: you should change the content-type of file for read a pdf file